# Android 2.2 Data Backup: How to backup when PreferenceActivity is used?

Tags: android, backup, preferenceactivity

I'd like to use the backup agent for saving user preferences:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

In the article, it's explained how to backup SharedPreferences:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html#SharedPreferences

However it's not explained how to backup when a PreferenceActivity (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) is used to save user preferences!

My application has a Setting Activity extending PreferenceActivity, which loads the settings from a preference.xml file (where a PreferenceScreen is configured). When the PreferenceActivity is displayed, the user can set the values of the preferences. How can I use the Data Backup API to save user data set with a PreferenceActivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharedPreferences is a Class with access to the preferences that the PreferenceActivity generats. In other word the default preferences use the sharedPreferences class the same way you would if you did it manualy. The key it usus is of course the key you gave it in the preferences.xml

Therefore you can use SharedPreferences as detailed in the link you provided with the settings which the preference activity added for you.

Comment: In that case, what should be the SharedPreferences file name to use for the PreferenceActivity. In the backup example with SharedPreferences the code is: `SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, PREFS);` with `PREFS = "user_preferences"`. user_preferences is the SharedPreference file name, which file name to use whith PreferenceActivity ?

Comment: If I remember correctly there is a default name for the preferences that android manages on it's on it's likely to be "user_preferences". I can check later when I have time, But you should manage I belive. You can also implement your own OnBackup and OnRestore and just extract the preferences by key

Comment: I found the answer, the file name used by a PreferenceActivity is _packagename_preferences_. It can be got with this code in PreferenceActivity: `String preferencesName = this.getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferencesName();`. Thank's for your help.